# Negritas en un <ion-textarea>

Tags: html, angular, ionic, ionic-framework

estoy buscando la manera de crear un botón que al darle click ponga en **negrita** una parte del texto dentro del

```
 <ion-textarea rows="15" placeholder="¡deja que tus ideas fluyan!"></ion-textarea>
```

Estuve investigando y puede ver que con:

```
  <div contenteditable="true">
    <b>Texto en Negrita</b>
    <br>
    Texto sin negrita
  </div>
```

Pero tampoco se como crear el botón que lo añada al texto seleccionado.

*Adicional, me gustaría saber como subiría a mi base de datos, con todo y formato.*

Answer (score 0):

tendrias que ponerle un hover a lo que desees se ponga en negrita. En el css

```
#tuId:hover {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Asi se pondra en negrita al pasar el mouse, para solucionar, espero te funcione :D

Para hacer entonces eso, tienes que hacer una funcion que al hacer click, haga eso

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">CAMBIAR A NEGRITA</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").style.fontWeight = "bold";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
}
```

Comment: Gracia!, pero eso me serviría al pasar el mouse, pero quiero que se ejecute al presionar un botón

Comment: Acabo de hacerte un ejemplo, para que lo apliques, efectivamente cambia el texto a negrita al hacer click, espero eso te ayude mejor